# “long long long” is too long for gcc?

Tags: gcc, spin, promela

[image]When I try to verify a model with ispin, I get an error of "long long long is too long for gcc". Is there a problem with my gcc?

Comment: Is `long long long` a thing?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth no, I am also wondering what is long long long

Comment: pretty darn strange that the error is in stdint.h - don't have one handy but I'm guessing a crazy preprocessor issue

Comment: BTW, saw your other question, I'm guessing you still have 16/32/64 bit installation incompatibilities.

Comment: I think this is a GCC "joke error message" pointing out that there is no such thing as `long long long`. Though I wonder who would write that in the first place, and to what avail. Maybe they meant to use that as a synonym for `__int128`?

Comment: I'm hoping it is a "joke error message."  I was curious about "long long long," so I put it in just to see what would happen, and when I saw that error I started laughing out loud.  If it's not meant to be a joke then maybe I need a break...

Answer (score 10):

Apparently, somewhere in your Promela code you have specified a 'long long long' type.  Here is how a simple C program misbehaves with such a declaration:

```
ebg@ebg$ cat ~/foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern int
main (void)
{
  long long long x;

  printf ("%lld", x>>32);
}
ebg@ebg$ gcc -o foo ~/foo.c
/Users/ebg/foo.c: In function 'main':
/Users/ebg/foo.c:6: error: 'long long long' is too long for GCC
```

Your incorrect use of 'long long long' should be obvious in your *.pml file; but, if you can't find it there, then look in pan.c (or pan.* files).

Comment: Did this not answer the question?